# How to open the file upload dialogue box When I click the Icon

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a React project, In that I have a card, In the card I have react icon so what

I am trying to do is If I click the react icon, then file upload dialogue box has to open

please someone help to achieve this I am using Reactstrap for this

This is my code Form.js

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import './Form.css';
import { MdCloudUpload } from 'react-icons/md';
import { Row,Col,Button,Modal,ModalBody,ModalFooter } from 'reactstrap'

const Form = () => {

    const inputFile = useRef(null)

    const onButtonClick = () => {
        inputFile.current.click();
    };

return (
        <Row>
            <Col md="6" sm="6" xs="6">

                <Modal isOpen={true}
                >
<ModalBody>
                        <Row>
                            <Col md="4" sm="4" xs="4">
                                <div className="image-upload">
                                    <input type='file' id='file' ref={inputFile} style={{ display: 'none' }}/>
                                        <MdCloudUpload onClick={onButtonClick} className=' icon'></MdCloudUpload>
                                </div>
                            </Col>
                            <Col md="8" sm="8" xs="8">
</Col>

                        </Row>


                    </ModalBody>
                    <ModalFooter>
                        <Button color="secondary">
                            Cancel
                </Button>
                        <Button type="submit" color="primary">
                            Submit
                </Button>
                    </ModalFooter>
                </Modal>
            </Col>
        </Row>
    )
}

export default Form
```

Comment: You should use <input type="file" /> instead simple button to be able to show upload dialogue

Comment: If I Click Icon then only I have to show file upload dialouge box. Here I don't need to use input tag.

Comment: You need it to show dialogue. Try something like this: <input id="file-input" type="file" name="name" style="display: none;" /><Button color="secondary" onClick={() => document.getElementById('file-input').click()}>Cancel</Button>

Answer (score 1):

there is two options:

1. use side library like `react-dropzone`
2. just add `<input type="file" />` and trigger change event it when icon is clicked

here is an example

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./Form.css";
import { MdCloudUpload } from "react-icons/md";

const Form = () => {
  const onIconClick = () => {
    const input = document.getElementById('file-input');

    if (input) {
       input.click();
    }
  };

  return (
    <Row>
      <Col md="6" sm="6" xs="6">
        <Modal isOpen={true}>
          <ModalBody>
            <Row>
              <Col md="4" sm="4" xs="4">
                <div className="image-upload">
                  <MdCloudUpload
                      className="icon"
                      onClick={onIconClick}
                  />
                  <input
                      type="file"
                      id="file-input"
                      style={{ display: 'none' }}
                  />
                </div>
              </Col>
              <Col md="8" sm="8" xs="8" />
            </Row>
          </ModalBody>
          <ModalFooter>
            <Button color="secondary">Cancel</Button>
            <Button type="submit" color="primary">
              Submit
            </Button>
          </ModalFooter>
        </Modal>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

Comment: If is it possible can you please give a solution @Nikita Prokofyev.

Comment: I've added an example how to trigger dialog, note that to handle a file you need to write onChange function for input

Comment: Above code is working fine but When I am trying to upload an image I am not able to see image in Circle.

Comment: can you please provide more details ? what circle?

Comment: I edited my code in my question please go through it once.

Comment: @Vamsi I still cannot figure out what circle are you talking about

Comment: Hi @Nikita Prokofyev please go through this link https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-fog-8fndj?file=/src/App.js

Comment: When I click the  Icon in circle file upload dialog box will open, but If I try to upload an Image then I am not unable to see that Image in Circle. That is what I want. @Nikita Prokofyev.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211386/discussion-between-nikita-prokofyev-and-vamsi).

Comment: @Vamsi I've edited code in sandbox, let me know if it works for you

Comment: Hi @ Nikita Prokofyev can you send me your sandbox code like me in comment section